# Multiple plots using dynamics

Tags: plotting, dynamic, list-manipulation

I am studying Dynamic and DynamicModule, and I have tried to make a simple plot of a family of real functions. The number of functions should be a dynamic variable controlled by a slider. So I have tried something like this

```
{Slider[Dynamic[z], {1, 4, 1}], Plot[Evaluate[Dynamic[Table[Sin[i*t], {i, 1, z}]]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]}
```

In this case variable `t` is highlighted in red and the output is empty. But if you do it outside of `Plot[]`, then you get a correct list of functions

```
{Slider[Dynamic[z], {1, 4, 1}], Evaluate[Dynamic[Table[Sin[i*t], {i, 1, z}]]]}
```

So, how one plots this kind of things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Plot` has to be within `Dynamic`, as the `Plot` needs to be updated when `z` is changed. You can't just update the content of `Plot` without making a new `Plot`.

```
{Slider[Dynamic[z], {1, 4, 1}], 
 Dynamic@Plot[Evaluate[Table[Sin[i*t], {i, 1, z}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]}
```

The syntax highlighting is due to the `Head` of your command inside `Plot` being `Dynamic`

```
Evaluate[Dynamic[Table[Sin[i*t], {i, 1, z}]]] // Head
```

> ```
> Dynamic
> ```

Comment: right, thank you)